# Ajax content load with database values not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to populate my div minimal_table through ajax onchange event based on the chosen dropdown value. The `<div class="minimal_table">` is the area of my page that I want to update every time I choose a value from my dropdown form. However, after my contents load, it returns no values from my database. I have checked the value being passed in my javascript using alert but it returns a right value. I also notice that it seems like it doesn't return true in the `other_function.php` `if(isset($val_id))`line even if I already chosen a value in the dropdown. Can somebody help me point out what is the wrong of my codes and what I am lacking? Thanks a lot. Here are my codes:

my_courses.php (ajax part)

```
$(':input').change(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        $('.minimal_table').html('<img src="../images/loading_trans.gif"  style="position:relative; margin:350px; margin-top:250px;" />');
        alert($(this).val());

       var val_id = $(this).val();
       var postData = {'val_id':val_id};

$.ajax({
  url: "../includes/other_functions.php",
  async: false,
  type: "POST",
  data: postData,
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data){
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.minimal_table').html(data);
    },2000);
     console.log(data);
  },
});

});
```

other_functions.php

```
<?php 
 function ajax_request_val(){

$val_id = $_POST['val_id'];
$field = "course_type";

if(isset($val_id)){

  $plans = db::getTable('plan',$field,$val_id);
            foreach ($plans as $plan) {
                if (eventAccessLevel(null, $plan['plan_id']) != EVENT_ACCESS_NONE) {
                    $course_array[] = getCourseDetails(null, $plan['plan_id']);
                    $pid_shown[] = $plan['plan_id'];
                }
            }
            $events = db::getTable('tbl_event',$field,$val_id);
            foreach ($events as $event) {
                if (!in_array($event['plan_id'], $pid_shown)) {
                    $event_id = $event['event_id'];
                    if (eventAccessLevel($event_id, null) != EVENT_ACCESS_NONE) {
                        $course_array[] = getCourseDetails($event_id, null);
                    }
                }
            }

            return $course_array;
}

else{

            $plans = db::getTable('plan');
            foreach ($plans as $plan) {
                if (eventAccessLevel(null, $plan['plan_id']) != EVENT_ACCESS_NONE) {
                    $course_array[] = getCourseDetails(null, $plan['plan_id']);
                    $pid_shown[] = $plan['plan_id'];
                }
            }
            $events = db::getTable('tbl_event');
            foreach ($events as $event) {
                if (!in_array($event['plan_id'], $pid_shown)) {
                    $event_id = $event['event_id'];
                    if (eventAccessLevel($event_id, null) != EVENT_ACCESS_NONE) {
                        $course_array[] = getCourseDetails($event_id, null);
                    }
                }
            }

            return $course_array;
 }  
}

?>
```

databaseconnect.php

```
public static function getTable($tableName,$field='',$type_id='') {
        if (!self::$db) self::connect();

        if(!empty($type_id)){
            $tableName = self::$db->escape_string($tableName);
            return self::getObjects('SELECT * FROM `' . $tableName . '` WHERE `'. $field .'` = `'. $type_id .'`;');
        }
        else{
            $tableName = self::$db->escape_string($tableName);
            return self::getObjects('SELECT * FROM `' . $tableName . '`;');
        }
    }
```

Output:

Initial load

[image]

Loading the form dropdown menu search

[image]

Choosing value from dropdown returns right value indicated by an alert

[image]

After content load (returns no value on the div mini_table)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `other_functions.php` you define the function `ajax_request_val()`.
As far as I can see, there is no call to that function within the same file, so when you call it with Ajax, you just define the function and never call it.

Comment: I included the other_function.php in my my_course.php and called the ajax_request_val function. In fact it works in initial load, however, whenever I chose a value from my dropdown, it seems that it never returns true in the if(isset($val_id)) condition that is why maybe no values returned.

Comment: it is the only function in my other_function.php

Comment: As also spotted by other answers, you need to call the function for it to actually run.

Answer (score 1):

You make an ajax call to other_functions.php but that file only contains a function that is never called.

There are lots of ways to approach this and tidy it up a bit but to fix the problem quickly you could try putting this at the top of other_functions.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax'])){ echo ajax_request_val(); }
```

and then change the data in your ajax call as follows

```
var postData = {val_id:val_id, ajax:1 }
```